# Can GeoServer serve hundreds of thousands of geoTIFFs?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I'm working on a project that is creating several hundred thousand GeoTIFFs.

Each GeoTIFF is a projection of species survivability, for the intersection of a climate future and a species. Unlike many of the "lots of GeoTIFFs" problems people have, these are all independent layers that will be viewed one at a time, and each one spans the world... so they cannot be mosaic-ed into a single big layer.

I [read on the GeoServer mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Serving-a-large-number-of-Geotiffs-td5256906.html#a5256977) that having tens of thousands of layers makes GS go slow, so I suspect it will be impractical for me to add all 300,000 layers to the catalog.

For an earlier version of this project, I scripted a web system around MapServer such that it would dynamically grab the source GeoTIFF on first request, then cache it for a while for subsequent tile requests.

Can I do something similar with GeoServer, or should I go back to trying to compile a working recent version of MapServer and MapScript/Python?

Edit: apparently I can use a mosaic with an extra dimension, like "species id", to treat all my GeoTIFFs as a single catalog entry. Will this work for millions of GeoTIFFs?

Comment: You do not likely need so many layers but you can use one layer as an image mosaic http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html. With MapServer I would have used tile index layer http://www.mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html.

Comment: Thanks user30184 but my tiffs aren't little parts of a big layer, they're all world-sized and need to be viewable independently of each other (I updated the question to be clearer about that)

Comment: It does not matter. There can be holes in the mosaic but when user zooms to desired area the correct image shows. It does not require much programming to store the bounding boxes of individual sites and offer shortcut for your users to find the location. If images overlap you can use view parameters for making a SQL like query to the index.

Comment: Most common use case is to use time as filtering parameter http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html but other parametes can be used as well but maybe not out-of-the-box.

Comment: You probably need [rasdaman](http://www.rasdaman.org/)

Comment: If each image has an unique ID that can be used for making a query it won't be a difficult task at all. Standard GeoServer or MapServer can handle everything on a single layer.

Comment: For my use case, any tile layer being viewed will only need parts from a single tiff. No tile layer will need to include parts of two of the source tiffs. Do I not understand mosaics? I thought the point of mosaic-ing was to combine multiple images that represented parts of the same conceptual layer

Comment: I looked at rasdaman, thanks nmtoken it looks pretty useful. The docs for serving tiles were all "TBD" however, so I decided to keep trying geoserver untill it works or fails completely..

Comment: You do understand mosaics but from too narrow point of view. Mosaic is an index that can be used to organize tiles side by side but there are more dimensions in the world. This OpenLayers demo is using some WMS that has a time-enabled mosaic, or maybe better word, index  http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wmst.html. Imagine that mosaic is a database. While the usual query is `select image from index where ST_Intersects(footprint,BBOX)` you can as well make the system to pick the right image for you with `select image from index where survivability_factor_1=xx and survivability_factor_2=yy`.

Comment: @user30184: Other parameters work out-of-the-box since 2.11.2 --> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171616/are-dimensions-attributes-other-than-time-and-elevation-possible/245973#245973

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GeoServer can handle hundreds of thousands of GeoTiffs and it will be very fast when only a few of them are loaded on each request.

This is possible using a single Imagemosaic with a PostGIS database, that has the species ID included. See [this solution](http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developers-corner-using-default-imagemosaic-cql-filter-in-geoserver/) based on **CQL Filters**. For good performance, create an Index on the species ID field in your database.

That article is a bit dated. It's possible to include **custom dimensions** already (since 2.11.2)

- [Are Dimensions/Attributes Other Than Time and Elevation Possible](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171616/are-dimensions-attributes-other-than-time-and-elevation-possible/245973#245973)

While custom dimensions will work, it will also blow up your GetCapabilities document, because it will include a list of all possible values, so the CQL method might be the way to go.

Make sure to limit the number of tiles per Request (*MaxAllowedTiles*).