# Can Geoserver let users choose a single tile from a layer to be displayed?

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have a raster layer of about 30 tiles. The rasters overlap and important data is hidden when the tiles are displayed as a layer. I'm wondered how others get around this issue? Can geoserver let users switch on and off individual tiles in a raster layer?

Answer (score 6):

Adding to [@IanTurton's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280440/115), you can also pass in a CQL_FILTER filtering on top of whatever attribute you have in the image mosaic index.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, it depends on how you would like them to be able to choose.

If you can specify a specific variable that users could use then probably yes. The standard variables are [TIME](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html) and [ELEVATION](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_time-elevationseries.html), but you can specify a [custom dimension](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171616/are-dimensions-attributes-other-than-time-and-elevation-possible/171839) too.

If you just want them to be able to select an arbitrary raster then I'm afraid the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks. The users will be loading the layer in ArcMap and would want to be able to single out a single image at a time so as not to miss any information obscured by the layer. One option in Geoserver is to create 30 layers of 1 tile. Not very elegant but perhaps that's the only way.

Comment: @Neil Did you ever find a better solution than creating 30 separate layers?

Comment: Sorry, i don't think I did. It was for a temporary project, now completed.