# Querying a custom dimension of a NetCDF raster with WMS

Tags: raster, geoserver, wms, netcdf

I have a NetCDF raster with mean temperatures, having this structure:

```
Dimensions:      (horizon: 13, percentiles: 3, lat: 213, lon: 274)
Coordinates:
  * lon          (lon) float32 -79.71 -79.63 -79.55 ... -57.13 -57.05 -56.96
  * lat          (lat) float32 62.62 62.54 62.46 62.37 ... 45.12 45.04 44.96
  * horizon      (horizon) datetime64[ns] 1951-01-01 1961-01-01 ...
2071-01-01
  * percentiles  (percentiles) int64 10 50 90
Data variables:
    tg_mean      (horizon, percentiles, lat, lon) float64 ...
```

I am serving this raster as a WMS layer with GeoServer (along with the NC plugin) and I'd like to know if there's a mechanism to select particular values for the dimensions, through the query. Given its type, it seems that `horizon` is automatically detected as the `TIME` dimension (as I can see in the "Layer -> Dimensions" tab of the GUI), which means I can use it in a query, but for `percentiles`, even though I can enable it as a "custom dimension" (in that same tab), I cannot figure out how to use it in the context of a query. Is that simply possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171616/are-dimensions-attributes-other-than-time-and-elevation-possible Dimensions are used by prefixing the dimension with DIM_ in the query.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer indeed, however it does not seem to be mentioned in the documentation. If you want to change your comment into an answer, I will "accept" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensions are used by prefixing the dimension with DIM_ in the query. Just add &DIM_PERCENTILES=*your value* to the query.

The DIM_ prefix is specified in the WMS specification and is not a GeoServer specific feature.

See [Are Dimensions/Attributes Other Than Time and Elevation Possible](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171616/are-dimensions-attributes-other-than-time-and-elevation-possible) for a similar discussion.